# how to verify mime type provided by $_FILES['userfile']['type']

Tags: php, image, file-upload, mime-types

I was reading through the documentation at [php.net link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and came along the following line:

> $_FILES['userfile']['type']
>
> ```
> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example 
> would be "image/gif". This mime type is however NOT checked on the PHP side 
> and therefore don't take its value for granted.
> ```

So how would one go about verifying that the file is of a proper mime type to prevent users from uploading potentially harmful files to the server; or otherwise causing bugs in code executed server side(since I might attempt to use a jpeg-only function on a file that isn't really a jpeg image)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `finfo_file` to find out what type PHP thinks the file is. However, I don't think this can be relied on, either. I believe it uses heuristics, it doesn't scan the entire file to make sure it's completely valid. E.g. if it begins with something like `<html>` it will say it's `text/html`, it's not going to parse the entire thing to make sure it's all correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getMimeType()
        {

                $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $type = $finfo->file($_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']);//change the field_name
                $mime = substr($type, 0, strpos($type, ';'));
                return $mime;

        }

        function isValidImage()
        {

            $mime = getMimeType();
            if(stristr($mime,'image'))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;

        }
        $res=isValidImage();
```

Try this it will check mime also.